# Cordova IOS 8.1 How to check for Network connection when app is opened

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ipad, cordova

When the user opens the app I want the app to check to see if the device is connected to the internet. Only want this to happen when the app is opened.

Any ideas, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the user is connected to the internet, not how good the connection is, you can use the cordova network plugin for it.

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.network-information

you can attach the check function to the deviceready event, so the check happens only on start.

Comment: This only works for me when I first install the app. If I close the app and then return to it again after doing something else on the iPad the deviceReady code block does not execute again because the device is consider still ready. How do I make it execute whenever I start the app from the home screen?

Comment: thats because the device ready event is only fired on start. If you load the app from the background without killing the process the event won't fired a second time. You can use for this case the device on resume event: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I didn't existed.